# How to read sysfs device path?

Tags: linux, usb, sysfs

I have a USB touchscreen connected to my hardware setup. and when I use `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` I get the following details about my device:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=2965 Product=5023 Version=0110
N: Name="Kortek Kortek Touch"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-3.4/input2
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.4/3-3.4:1.2/0003:2965:5023.0006/input/input7
U: Uniq=S20131028
H: Handlers=mouse1 event7 js0
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3
B: MSC=10
```

I want to know what does the line `S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.4/3-3.4:1.2/0003:2965:5023.0006/input/input7` means. How to read it ? What are the numbers in the path ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Sysfs` attribute is the location of that device within the sysfs filesystem. Assuming your kernel was compiled with `CONFIG_SYSFS` and the sysfs filesystem is mounted to `/sys`, you can view the device at:

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.4/3-3.4:1.2/0003:2965:5023.0006/input/input7
```

To break down what path represents:

`/sys/` is the mountpoint of the sysfs filesystem (see the output of `mount | grep sysfs`).

`/devices/` contains a filesystem representation of the device tree ([source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt)).

`/pci0000:00/` describes the PCI domain and the bus number. In this case, the domain number is `0000` and the bus number is `00` ([source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs-pci.txt)).

`/0000:00:14.0/` has the the PCI domain and bus number repeated, along with the slot and function. In this case, the USB device's slot number is `14` and its function number is `0` ([source](http://cromwell-intl.com/linux/sysfs.html)).

`/usb3/` refers to USB controller attached to bus number `3` ([source](http://www.linux-usb.org/FAQ.html#i6)).

`/3-3/3-3.4/3-3.4:1.2/` has redundant information. The last `/3-3.4:1.2/` means you are referring to the USB controller attached to bus `3`, port `3`, port `4`, configuration number `1` and interface number `2` ([source](http://www.linux-usb.org/FAQ.html#i6)).

`/0003:2965:5023.0006/` means the device is attached to bus `0003`, has a vendor ID of `2965`, and a product ID of `5023`.

Comment: I am aware of that. What I am asking is what does the path tells us about the device like "pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.4/3-3.4:1.2/0003:2965:5023.0006". What does the numbers in the path say about the device ?

Comment: Let me know if I should clarify more...

Comment: what does the number `0006` mean in `/0003:2965:5023.0006/`

Comment: I don't know for sure... maybe it is the revision number? See if it matches the Rev property of your device in `/sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices`

Comment: `Rev= 1.00` So it does not seem to match it. However, there is one more property `Dev#=  6`. Do you know what this is ?

Comment: `0006` is the device number that gets assigned by the kernel. A device number will NOT be re-used by the kernel, so if you unplug and replug the device, you should see the device number counting up (i.e. `0006`, then `0007`, then `0008`, and so on). An easy way to check would be to use `lsusb`.